# App bar should not expand while clicking

Tags: c#, xaml, cordova, windows-phone-8, appbar

I am developing Windows Phone 8 PhoneGap app. I have requirement like when clicking app bar, It should not expand for some pages. My app bar is already in minimized mode. I would like to know how to achieve that.

Comment: Could you maybe add a *bit* more details about what you've tried (if anything)? Any code? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to control the behaviour of the application bar when the user is interacting with it.

All you can do is set it's content and mode.

If you don't want a minimized application bar to expand when tapped then what purpose is the application bar on that page? The minimized application bar is intended to hide it's content away so the user has to tap it to interact with it.